# Google App ScriptError - 401 UNAUTHENTICATED after redeplyment

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

I'm getting this below exception while running the script after redeployment.Earlier it was working fine but when I added some new functions and redeployed it as API executable., started getting this error.

```
[17-07-08 20:48:45:404 PDT] {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "ScriptError",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError",
        "errorMessage": "Authorization is required to perform that action.",
        "errorType": "ScriptError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OAuth scopes have probably changed. Your client needs to add these new scopes and request a new token with them.